Can std::make_shared cowork with operator new?
It is said that

std::make_shared uses ::new, so if any special behavior has been set up using a class-specific operator new, it will differ from std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...)).

So, given the following class, if we use std::make_shared<MyClass>(), then nothing could be observed by Tracker.
class MyClass
{
public:
    static void operator delete(void * ptr, std::size_t sz)
    {
        Tracker::deallocated(sz);
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }

    static void operator delete[](void * ptr, std::size_t sz)
    {
        Tracker::deallocated(sz);
        ::operator delete[](ptr);
    }
    static void * operator new(std::size_t sz)
    {
        Tracker::allocated(sz);
        return ::operator new(sz);
    }

    static void * operator new[](std::size_t sz)
    {
        Tracker::allocated(sz);
        return ::operator new[](sz);
    }
}

However, I don't want a customized ::new either. So I wonder what can I do to tracker all memory allocated/deallocated MyClass.

" I don't want a customized ::new either." what do you want then?

Have a look at : std::allocate_shared, and move your allocation code out of your class into a custom allocator (which is IMO better separation of concerns)

fwiw, here a mre: https://godbolt.org/z/PYePfebzP

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I want something which has a "local effect", and doesn't involves much change to code.

Are you trying to detect leaks, or simply tracking how much memory is used by MyClass instances? Because you can do the latter using constructor/destructor if you don't mind capturing stack instances as well.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai three points. First, std::make_shared is supposed to only make one allocation for both the object and the shared_ptr control data, while shared_ptr(new) makes two allocations. Second, it appears he wants minimum code change. Third, it's kind of dangerous to have a system (like this tracker system) that will just ignore some things silently -- compiler errors are great, runtime errors are okay-ish, silently ignoring things... not great at all. Whether or not his "tracking" is really best accomplished via new -- who knows.

what are you willing to change on existing code? Would it be acceptable to call std::make_shared<MyClass>(new OtherClass{}) ?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai No, because it is not considered as a best practice by some people, thus can't pass code review. However, what Sebastian said is ok. I can actually use constructors and deconstructors. Moreover, I want to know if there are some other ways, since a class may have many constructors, and a custom constructor will make the class non-trivial.

this seems to be a xy-problem. Rather than focusing the question on  std::make_shared (the quote already says it all, its not using the new you defined but ::new, and you dont want ::new, so thats a dead end) you should ask us about the underlying problem you are trying to solve (explain what you want to track, ask how to keep the class trivial if thats a requirement etc.)

As @PepijnKramer pointed out, you'd better use std::allocate_shared instead of std::make_shared. It helps separate different concerns. The difficult part would be to define a tracking_allocator template class to pass as the first argument to std::allocate_shared:
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct tracking_allocator{

//'std::allocate_shared' demand{
    template<typename U>
    struct rebind
    { using other = struct tracking_allocator<U>; };
    
    template<typename U>
    operator tracking_allocator<U>() const { return{}; };
//}'std::allocate_shared' demand;


    static T*  allocate(std::size_t n){
        static_assert(std::is_empty_v<tracking_allocator>, "allocator must be empty class");
        return /*alloc and track 'n' elements of 'T'*/;
    }; //! allocate(n);

    static void deallocate(T* ptr, std::size_t n){
        return /*dealloc and track 'n' elements of 'T' at starting at 'ptr'*/;
    }; //! deallocate(ptr,n);

    static void construct(T* ptr, auto&& ... args){
        // do some tracking ...
        std::construct_at(ptr, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }; //! construct(ptr,args...);

    static void destroy(T* ptr){
        // do some tracking ...
        std::destroy_at(ptr);
        // do more tracking ...
    }; //! destroy(ptr);

}; //! tracking_allocator<T>;

Now you can use tracking_allocator as an opt in:
constexpr bool is_debug_mode = /*use std or tracking alloc*/;

using my_allocator = std::conditional_t<
                          is_debug_mode,
                          tracking_allocator<myclass>,
                          std::allocator<myclass>>;

auto myptr=std::allocate_shared<myclass>(my_allocator{});

Your tracking logic is now totally separate from class definition & can be switched on and off via is_debug_mode. You can also exploit the allocator argument to std::allocate_shared:
auto my_next_ptr=std::allocate_shared<myclass>(std::allocator<myclass>{});

But this is less flexible than the primary approach. So, you can define your opt in make function for convenience:
auto make_myclass()
{ return std::allocate_shared(my_allocator{}); };

auto myptr = make_myclass();

You may make any of the above classes and functions templates; but it would over-complicate this post as an illustration.
